# How do you write ImageData to an HTML5 canvas context?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, imagedata

I am able to generate a new `ImageData` object, but not able to render that to a canvas context. For some reason, the canvas 2d context does not like the ImageData objects *it created*.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var width = 50;
var height = 50;


var ci = ctx.createImageData(width,height); // ImageData { width: ..., height: ..., data: Uint8ClampedArray(10000) }

// Draw on ci ImageData object...

ctx.drawImage(ci, 0, 0, width, height);
```

However, this throws an error:

```
TypeError: Argument 1 of CanvasRenderingContext2D.drawImage could not be converted to any of: HTMLImageElement, SVGImageElement, HTMLCanvasElement, HTMLVideoElement, ImageBitmap.
```

#### How do you write an `ImageData` object to a canvas?

Comment: [**`putImageData`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/putImageData)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To write an `ImageData` object back to the canvas, you must use [context.putImageData() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/putImageData).

```
var ci = ctx.createImageData(width,height);
ctx.putImageData(ci, 0, 0);
```